# How do I synchronize a SQlite database between multiple instances of the same Python script/executable?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have a CRUD application. Uses SQlite3 database and Python. Everything works well. Absolutely no issues code functions as expected.

When I instantiate a ***second*** instance of my python program and enter data in the ***first*** instance it does not automatically sync or update the view in the second instance. How do I get the second instance to sync and refresh the display please?

1 - So I run my python script and everything works well. I am happy.

2 - I decide to run a second instance of my python script and everything works as expected.

3 - I add a record in the first instance. Everything is ok.

4 - The record I added is not immediately synced in the second instance.

5 - If I close the second instance and re-instantiate it then the data shows up.

So how do I get the second instance to sync the data without having to close and re-instantiate please? The database source code is below..

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS map(
            id Integer Primary Key,
            name text,
            description text,
            tod text,
            day text,
            givenby text
        )
        """        
        
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        self.con.commit()

    # Insert Function
    def insert(self, name, description, tod, day, givenby):
        self.cur.execute("insert into map values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?)",
                         (name, description, tod, day, givenby))
        self.con.commit()

    # Fetch All Data from DB
    def fetch(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * from map")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        # print(rows)
        return rows

    # Delete a Record in DB
    def remove(self, id):
        self.cur.execute("delete from map where id=?", (id,))
        self.con.commit()

    # Update a Record in DB
    def update(self, id, name, description, tod, day, givenby):
        self.cur.execute(
            "update map set name=?, description=?, tod=?, day=?, givenby=? where id=?",
            (name, description, tod, day, givenby, id))
        self.con.commit()
```

The code for showing the data is below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

from db import Database
db = Database("map.db")

from datetime import datetime


print('MAP Tracking System is loading... please wait! This may take a while but still faster than Windows update. ')


root = Tk()
root.title("MAP Tracking & Management System")
root.geometry("1820x920+0+0")
root.config(bg="#2c3e50")

#root.state("zoomed")

name    = StringVar()
description = StringVar()
tod     = StringVar() #tod = (t)ime (o)f (d)ay
day     = StringVar()
givenby = StringVar()

# Entries Frame
entries_frame = Frame(root, bg="#535c68")
entries_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
title = Label(entries_frame, text="Huntley MAP Tracking & Management System", font=("Calibri", 18, "bold"), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
title.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20, sticky="w")

lblName = Label(entries_frame, text="Name", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
lblName.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

txtName = Entry(entries_frame, textvariable=name, font=("Calibri", 16), width=30)
txtName.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

lblDescription = Label(entries_frame, text="Description", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
lblDescription.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

txtDescription = Entry(entries_frame, textvariable=description, font=("Calibri", 16), width=30)
txtDescription.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

lbldob = Label(entries_frame, text="Time", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
lbldob.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

txtdob = Entry(entries_frame, textvariable=tod, font=("Calibri", 16), width=30)
txtdob.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

lblday = Label(entries_frame, text="Day", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
lblday.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

txtday = Entry(entries_frame, textvariable=day, font=("Calibri", 16), width=30)
txtday.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")


lblgivenby = Label(entries_frame, text="Given By", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="#535c68", fg="white")
lblgivenby.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

txtgivenby = Entry(entries_frame, textvariable=givenby, font=("Calibri", 16), width=30)
txtgivenby.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

tod.set("Auto Captured")
day.set("Auto Captured")


def getData(event):
    selected_row = tv.focus()
    data = tv.item(selected_row)
    global row
    row = data["values"]
    print("Row Data Below")
    print(row)
    name.set(row[1])
    description.set(row[2])
    tod.set(row[3])
    day.set(row[4])
    givenby.set(row[5])

def dispalyAll():
    tv.delete(*tv.get_children())
    for row in db.fetch():
        tv.insert("", END, values=row)

def add_employee():
    if txtName.get() == "" or txtDescription.get() == "" or txtdob.get() == "" or txtday.get() == "" or txtgivenby.get() == ""  :
        messagebox.showerror("Erorr in Input", "Please Fill All the Details")
        return
        
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    current_day  = now.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y") #%A=Weekday %d=date %B=Monthname %Y=Year 
    #print("Current Time =", current_time)    
        
    tod.set("")
    tod.set(current_time)
    
    day.set("")
    day.set(current_day)
    #txtdob.insert(END, current_time)
        
    db.insert(txtName.get(),txtDescription.get(), txtdob.get() ,txtday.get(), txtgivenby.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Record Inserted")
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()

def update_employee():
    if txtName.get() == "" or txtDescription.get() == "" or txtdob.get() == "" or txtday.get() == "" or txtgivenby.get() == "" :
        messagebox.showerror("Erorr in Input", "Please Fill All the Details")
        return
    db.update(row[0],txtName.get(), txtDescription.get(), txtdob.get(), txtday.get(), txtgivenby.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Record Update")
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()


def delete_employee():
    db.remove(row[0])
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()


def clearAll():
    name.set("")
    description.set("")
    tod.set("")
    day.set("")
    givenby.set("")
    

btn_frame = Frame(entries_frame, bg="#535c68")
btn_frame.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
btnAdd = Button(btn_frame, command=add_employee, text="Add Details", width=15, font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"), fg="white",
                bg="#16a085", bd=0).grid(row=0, column=0)
btnEdit = Button(btn_frame, command=update_employee, text="Update Details", width=15, font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"),
                 fg="white", bg="#2980b9",
                 bd=0).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
btnDelete = Button(btn_frame, command=delete_employee, text="Delete Details", width=15, font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"),
                   fg="white", bg="#c0392b",
                   bd=0).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
btnClear = Button(btn_frame, command=clearAll, text="Clear Details", width=15, font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"), fg="white",
                  bg="#f39c12",
                  bd=0).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)

# Table Frame
tree_frame = Frame(root, bg="#ecf0f1")
tree_frame.place(x=0, y=300, width=1980, height=520)
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", font=('Calibri', 18),
                rowheight=45)  # Modify the font of the body
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 18))  # Modify the font of the headings
tv = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), style="mystyle.Treeview")
tv.heading("1", text="ID")
tv.column("1", width=5)
tv.heading("2", text="Name")
tv.heading("3", text="Description")
tv.column("3", width=5)
tv.heading("4", text="Time")
tv.column("4", width=10)
tv.heading("5", text="Day")
tv.column("5", width=35)
tv.heading("6", text="Given By")

tv['show'] = 'headings'

tv.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", getData)   
tv.bind("<Return>", getData)

tv.pack(fill=X)

dispalyAll()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no code on showing the data, so how can we identify the issue?

Comment: @acw1668 my apologies in my haste I have forgotten to include the code for displaying data. I have added it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can monitor the update of the database file by checking its modification time:

```py
import os
...

def monitor_db_change(last_change=None):
    # get last modification time of the db file
    stamp = os.stat("map.db").st_mtime
    if stamp != last_change:
        # db has been changed, update treeview
        dispalyAll()
        last_change = stamp
    root.after(1000, monitor_db_change, last_change)

# start the monitor task
monitor_db_change()
#dispalyAll()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @acw1688 thank you so much your code works like a charm. I did not know about tkinter .after, I learnt many things with your code. My only concern is the final application will be deployed on a network drive and will the checking of the database update time every second affect other apps running on the server? On my desktop at home everything is smooth no hiccups and works like magic. Thank you very much once again!